# How to solve cnosdb-cli throwing 'unexpected EOF during chunk size line'?

Tags: cnosdb

When I use --chunked in cli to query SQL, it throws

```
request or response body error: error reading a body from connection: unexpected EOF during chunk size line
```

What is the reason and how can I fix it